# Does an ascii equivalent of 0x80 exist?

Tags: ascii

Does anybody know the ASCII equivalent of 80(hexadecimal)? Does it even exist? I was just wondering, the table only goes up to 7F.

Comment: To save everyone the time of going to Wikipedia, 7F is 127 in decimal, and there are only 128 characters in ASCII (index is zero-based)

Answer (score 10):

No.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is by definition a 7-bit character code, with encodings from 0 to 127 (`0x7F`). Anything outside that range is not ASCII.

There are a number of 8-bit and wider character codes *based on* ASCII (sometimes, with questionable accuracy, called "extended ASCII") that assign some meaning to `0x80`.  For example, both [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) treat `0x80` as a control character, while [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) uses it for the Euro symbol.

Comment: Unicode shouldn't treat 0x80 as anything since it's not an encoding. Could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: I wasn't referring to the encoding `0x80`, I was referring to the code point, U+0080. UTF-8 (one of several encodings for Unicode) uses a 2-byte encoding for the `U+0080`.