# How to convert a hex list to a list of ASCII values?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

Let's use as an example the hex string 0x790x760x7d0x7d0x80.

```py
ct=input()
hex_list=ct.split('0x')
print(hex_list)
ascii_values=[]
for i in hex_list:
    if i!="" :
       (ascii_values).append(ascii(i))
print(ascii_values)
```

I'm getting this output:

```py
['', '79', '76', '7d', '7d', '80']
["'79'", "'76'", "'7d'", "'7d'", "'80'"]
```

But the desired output would be the hex values converted into ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will convert from to a list of bytes to ASCII, but 0x80 is invalid ASCII character code. See below:

```
ct = '0x790x760x7d0x7d0x80'
hex_list = ct.split('0x')
ascii_values=[]
for i in hex_list:
    print(i)
    if i != '':
        try:
            bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(i)
            ascii_string = bytes_object.decode("ASCII")
            ascii_values.append(ascii(ascii_string))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print('Invalid ASCII... skipping...')
print(ascii_values)
```

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979796/does-an-ascii-equivalent-of-0x80-exist) regarding 0x80.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat the strings as a series of groups of four characters. From each group, drop the `0x` prefix using string slicing and `zip()`, and then you can use `map()` to turn the tuples from `zip()` into strings representing the desired hex values.

From there, you can turn these strings into the desired characters using `int()` to get the integer value that the string represents, and `chr()` to get the corresponding ASCII character.

```py
data = "0x790x760x7d0x7d0x80"
ascii_values = list(map(''.join, zip(data[2::4], data[3::4])))
result = [chr(int(val, 16)) for val in ascii_values]

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
['y', 'v', '}', '}', '\x80']
```

Comment: And if you want a string, then `result = ''.join(chr(......) for ....)`